# Как сделать игру на c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю некое подобие игры на wpf, и мне интересно как можно сделать, чтоб другие программы определяли моё приложение как игру? Чтоб, например, какой-нибудь msi afterburner мог отображать статистику.

Comment: Подозреваю, что у программ вроде msi afterburner имеется своя бд с перечнем игр и они берут информацию из нее, а не пытаются определить что является игрой самостоятельно

Comment: Как вариант, ваше приложение должно использовать DirectX, OpenGL, Vulkan и тд и работать в режиме полного экрана, но это не точно